# Multiple accounts to a website application

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I have an WindowsForms application written in C# which starts a number of threads for logging in on a site with different users' accounts. I use a WebBrowser control to navigate from the login page to the main page.

My problem is I can only authenticate with one user account, all threads are connected to the same account because the site uses cookies to store a sessionID. How can I store multiple sessions to simulate the authentication from different browsers?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible because of existing session merging policies present in Internet Explorer - WebBrowser is the IE's emulation layer, so it abides to the same principles. A good read on the topic is available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/05/06/session-cookies-sessionstorage-and-ie8.aspx).

To go around this issue, you will have to go further than simply using the control, but rather access IE on a lower level.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. I used other method, instead of creating threads I started instances of a program which use the WebBrowser control and it works. What is the difference between these ways to use the WebBrowser? In the method using threads the WebBrowser is not declared static so it is not shared, it is because it is in the same address space ?