# How to login with different accounts at the same time with .net webbrowser control in C#

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, cookies, webbrowser-control

I would like to create an application, that contains two or more webbrowser controls. I would like to login to a website, that uses cookies, but when I logged in with one of the browsers, it replaces the others cookies/settings of course. Is this a solution to use parallel accounts to the same site? Using different proxies on each webbrowser would be awesome.

**UPDATE :**

Other webbrowsers (based on firefox or anything else) or wrappers would be also nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559223/multiple-accounts-to-a-website-application

Comment: @Lloyd only partially - it doesn't provide a solution, only an explanation...

Comment: @Yahia - it's still a duplicate question. But I agree it deserves a 2nd chance.

Comment: Using the .Net Webbrowser control I do not believe there is "much" of a genuine solution, is there?

Comment: @Lloyd regarding WebBrowser control I agree, since the OP updated the question to include possible alternatives/browsers it is solvable IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

What you describe is usually not wanted/supported because of [Session Merging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/05/06/session-cookies-sessionstorage-and-ie8.aspx).

There is a .NET browser-framework (based on Chrome/WebKit) which supports what you want... for details see http://awesomium.com/

Answer (score 4):

It is IE behavior so you will have your sessions merged, you can try logging in twice from plain IE to see the effect and explore the possibilities.

It might still be possible, you would have to run each WebControl as a different (local-machine) User somehow. The session is linked to a cookie and cookies are stored per User.

Comment: newer IE versions can be started (same user) with `-nomerge` option on the commandline to make this work BUT that is NOT available from the COM interface (which in turn is the base for the .NET WebBrowser control)...

Comment: @Yahia - interesting, sounds like another tiny opening.